# Create dynamic html content on form submit/button click without Page Refresh

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form in which I should be able to define multiple random amounts of people.

Instead I prepare the form rows in advance :

```
 <div>Person 1: <label>Name:<input type="text"></label> <!-- rest of form elements --></div>
 <div>Person 1: <label>Name:<input type="text"></label> <!-- rest of form elements --></div>
 <div>Person 1: <label>Name:<input type="text"></label> <!-- rest of form elements --></div>
 <div>Person 1: <label>Name:<input type="text"></label> <!-- rest of form elements --></div>
....
```

I would like to add some interaction:

[image]
The most desired way is to place an additional form whereby user can add person (html markup for presentation and hidden inputs for further `$_POST` handling) into existing part of form, without page reloading.

**How should I go about it ?**

I have three ideas:

1. `click function`

   ```
   $('#addperson').click(function() {
       //take values from form elements
       var $form = $(this).parents('.passengersform')
       var $name = $form.children('input.name').val();
       var $phone ...
       var $type ...
       var $info ...

       // append it 
       $('.passengers').append('<div> Here goes visible part of html</div>');
       $form.append('<div>Here goes inputs type hidden for main form submit </div>');
       // clear the form
   });
   ```
2. Send / recieve data using AJAX :

   - Send ajax post to server
   - prepare markup on server side and `echo` result
   - `appendd()` / `html()` recived data when success
3. Click button to append new row of form elements to fill them <- a bit differently than the picture above but still its better than empty slots

Perhaps you know of a plugin designed for this purpose?

Comment: You could create a container at the top to show added person. You could add jquery event for form submit and make ajax post on success function append the fields from form to container. Or You could have Save/Submit button on container with added person. show added persons info on container with each Add Click person. On Submit click do Ajax submit and get Submit success /failure for each individual. Do validations before calling ajax submit call on backend.

Comment: _"I have form"_ Can include `html` of `form` at Question ? Could try cloning existing `form` children `html` , appending to parent `form` element

Comment: I think ajax would be the best rout here if you want to save to a database each time 'add persion' is clicked.

Comment: This form is only part of a bigger one. It's not for sending data, database operations etc. It should only add dynamic HTML content - precisely form elements filled by user - which will be sent later with rest of fields

Answer (score 2):

In your form, add the attribute onsubmit to return a JavaScript function. Make sure that in the function, you do return false so the page does not refresh after the form submit.

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
```

And in your JavaScript, you can make a function that will do the validation with Ajax or not, and then append it to your list.

I made a quick example available here: JSFiddle

Answer (score 1):

I used pure javascript to create the magic, trick is you need to get the control of form, which you can do using this button:

```
<button class="submit" onclick="return submtBtn()"type="submit">
```

javascript code is also quite catchy

```
function submtBtn(){
    var tr="<tr>";
  tr+="<td>"+document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value+"</td>";
  tr+="<td>"+document.getElementsByName('Telephone')[0].value+"</td>";
  tr+="<td>"+document.getElementsByName('Type')[0].value+"</td></tr>";


var table=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

table.innerHTML=table.innerHTML+tr;
console.log(tr);
    return false;
}
```

you are not letting submit the form because there is not need, and you are getting the work done. here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gj4rd81s/)